# python/pandas - get results from searching two columns

Tags: python, pandas

For my dataframe below, I am trying to list the columns results if col1 contains a string and col2 is equal to another string. I keep getting errors like: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Data:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = ['UNIVERSITY OF CONN. OF','UNIVERSITY OF CONNECTICUT','ONTARIO','UNIV. OF TORONTO','ALASKA DEPT.OF']
l3 = ['US','US','CA','CA',np.NaN]
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_id':l1,'org':l2,'country':l3})
df
```

Try 1:

```
df[['org','country']]\
    [(df['org'].str.contains('UNIVERSITY OF CONN',na=False))] and \
    [df['country'] == 'US']
```

Try 2:

```
df[['org','country']]\
    [(df['org'].str.contains('UNIVERSITY OF CONN',na=False)) and df['country'] == 'US']
```

This works but it only searches for a single column not multiple. When I add `and` and other `contains` it errors out (with above error):

```
df[['org','country']]\
    [df['org'].str.contains('UNIVERSITY OF CONN',na=False)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In pandas you use `bitwise &`  instead of `and`. df[(df['org'].str.contains('UNIVERSITY OF CONN',na=False)) & (df['country'] == 'US')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to `and` the results of your dataframe/series operations, it tries to see if `df1 and df2`. Which means that it tries to see whether the resulting dataframes are `True`. There is no concept of a dataframe being `True` in pandas, so it returns that error to you.

The correct way to do what you are trying to do is to use a bitwise and operator: `&`. In this scenario, it will compare every corresponding row instead of the whole dataframe/series. So, your code should be:

```
df[['org','country']][(df['org'].str.contains('UNIVERSITY OF CONN', na=False)) & (df['country'] == 'US')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Vaishali, we have to use the bitwise `&` instead of `and`.

```py
matches_org = df["org"].str.contains("UNIVERSITY OF CONN", na=False)
matches_country = df["country"] == "US"

matches_org_and_country = df[matches_org & matches_country]
```

To filter, we always pass a boolean series into `df`. When combining two filters, we combine two boolean series elementwise.

If you want to use `and` and `or` a lot, look into [`pd.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

#### Bitwise And

```
>>> pd.Series([True, True, False]) & pd.Series([True, False, True])
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

#### Bitwise Or

```
>>> pd.Series([True, True, False]) | pd.Series([True, False, True])
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```